# How can I print the values of a Entry() in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Im just simply trying to print the values of the entry fields and it tells me its not defined. I been looking online for a long while now. The lastest thing that I tried was adding `self` as a parameter of `add_student` but that didn't work.

This is the code

```
from tkinter import *

class window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.widgets()

    def add_student(self):
        print(f"Student's name (first, last): {self.fname_textbox}, {self.lname_textbox}")

    def widgets(self):

        self.master.title("Student Test Score & Grade")
        self.master.minsize(200,200)

        """ Labels """
        # First name
        self.fname_label = Label(root, text='First Name: ')
        self.fname_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        # Last Name
        self.lname_label = Label(root, text='Last name: ')
        self.lname_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        """ Entry boxes """
        # First Name
        self.fname_textbox = Entry(root, width=30)
        self.fname_textbox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)

        # Last name
        self.lname_textbox = Entry(root, width=30)
        self.lname_textbox.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)

        """ Buttons """
        # Add Button
        self.add_btn = Button(root, text="Add Student", command=self.add_student).grid(row=4, column=2, padx=2, pady=2)

if __name__=="__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app = window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

It prints this

```
Student's name (first, last): .!entry, .!entry2
```

Instead of: `Student's name (first, last): John, Doe`

What does this mean?

Comment: When you call `.add_student()` during your `__init__()`,  `.widgets()` has not yet been called and therefore none of your widgets actually exist.  Move that call down a line - or get rid of it completely, presumably the call due to the button click is the one you actually want to happen.

Comment: Then it throws a NameError. ```NameError: name 'add_student' is not defined```.

Comment: Oh, you need the `self.` in front of it in the button's `command=` as well.

Comment: Right, that fixed that issue. Now, its not actually printing what I type into the Entry() textboxes. It returns ```Student's name (first, last): .!entry, .!entry2```

Comment: `self.fname_textbox` (for example) is the *Entry widget itself*.  `self.fname_textbox.get()` is the *contents* of that Entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value of the entries in order to use them in your print statement
You do this by putting:

```
firstname = self.fname_textbox.get() 
lastname = self.1fname_textbox.get()
```

before you print and using these values in your print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Try something like this:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.nameEntry = Entry(master)
    self.contents = StringVar()
    self.nameEntry["textvariable"]=self.contents
    self.nameEntry.pack()
    self.nameEntry.grid(row=0,column=1)
    self.buttonSave = Button(master,text="Save",command=self.save).grid(row=9,columnspan=2, sticky=W+E+N+S)

def save(self):
    print self.nameEntry.get()
```

Comment: Took both functions into a file and this is what I got...                                                      ``` File "win.py", line 12
    print self.nameEntry.get()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```